# Which option removes limit of continuation lines in Intel Fortran?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I am writing a Fortran code which needs many continuation lines (thousands)

I found gfortran can compile without problem, however, ifort will complain that

> catastrophic error: Statement too long

and the compilation is aborted.

Is there an option that can make ifort ignore the continuation lines limit?

Comment: Why do you need so many continuation lines?

Comment: Just for my own curiosity, which branch of mathematics or physics generates such long expressions? I understand they are generated automatically by some algebra system or similar.

Comment: @VladimirF it is a large matrix expression generated by mathematica, and I am lazy to transform it to sparse style and want to embed it in a single step.

Answer (score 4):

There is a limit in the standard for the number of continuation lines. A processor may be less strict, but still will have limits. I don't think you can change that hard limit.

According to http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Continuation+lines

> The Intel Fortran compiler allows up to 511 lines by default, or 255
>   with -stand f95. The warning message is:
>
> warning #5199: Too many continuation lines

the warning refers to more than 255 but less than 512, so  it is not relevant to you.

This thread from 2007 also confirms 511 is a hard limit https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/268739

What you can do is to use very long lines which exceed the 132 characters limit of the Fortran standard (other compilers may require a flag to allow this). That is a recommendation of @SteveLionel in that thread.

Comment: -extend-source applies only to fixed-form source and changes the line length from 72 to 132.. With free-form, ifort allows individual lines to be much longer, up to around 4000 characters if I recall correctly.

Comment: OK, so it is the default. I knew these options from gfortran and Cray but couldn't find the option for Intel.